Induction proof of $\pi-\lambda$ theorem
A $\pi$-system on a set $X$ is a collection $\mathcal P$ of subsets of $X$ closed under finite intersections. (For our purposes $\varnothing, X \in\mathcal P$.)
A $\lambda$-system on $X$ is a collection $\mathcal L$ of subsets of $X$ such that $X \in \mathcal L$ and $\mathcal L$ is closed under proper differences (i.e., if $A, B \in \mathcal L$ and $A \subseteq B,$ then $B\setminus A \in \mathcal L$) and countable unions of disjoint sets. Observe that $\lambda$-systems are also closed under countable increasing unions.
Let $\mathcal P$ and $\mathcal L$ be an arbitrary $\pi$-system and $\lambda$-system, respectively.
Theorem. Whenever $\mathcal P \subseteq \mathcal L,$ then $\sigma(\mathcal P) \subseteq \mathcal L,$ where $\sigma(\mathcal P)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathcal P.$
I already know a proof of this statement, but I am interested in proofs that use transfinite induction. Does anyone know where I can find such a proof?
In any case, below is my attempt to prove the theorem. I'll be thankful to whoever points out any mistakes or suggests ways to improve the proof.

Proof.
First note that, whenever $A, B, A\cap B$ are all in $\mathcal L,$ their union
$$ A \cup B = (A \cap B) \cup (A \setminus (A \cap B)) \cup (B \setminus (A \cap B))$$
is in $\mathcal L.$ Let $\mathcal P'$ be any $\pi$-system contained in $\mathcal L.$ Let's prove by induction that for any $A_1, \dots, A_n \in \mathcal P',$ their union is in $\mathcal L.$ We have just proved the case $n = 2.$ Assume the result holds for a certain $n,$ and let $A_1, \dots, A_{n+1} \in \mathcal P'.$ Then by induction hypothesis both $A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_n$ and
$$(A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_n) \cap A_{n+1} = (A_1 \cap A_{n+1}) \cup \cdots \cup (A_n \cap A_{n+1})$$ are in $\mathcal L.$ The claim is proved by applying the case $n =2.$
Let $\mathcal B_0 = \mathcal P.$ For $\alpha \ge 1,$ define inductively $\mathcal A_\alpha$ to be the class consisting of countable unions of sets, each from some previous $\mathcal B_\beta$. Define $\mathcal B_\alpha$ to be the class consisting of all the differences $A \setminus B$ for $A, B \in \mathcal A_\alpha.$
Let $\alpha \ge 1$ and suppose that $\mathcal B_\beta$ is a $\pi$-system contained in $\mathcal L$ for every $\beta < \alpha.$ This is certainly the case for $\alpha = 1.$
Note that $$\mathcal A_{<\alpha} = \bigcup_{\beta < \alpha} \mathcal B_{\beta}$$ is a $\pi$-system contained in $\mathcal L.$ Hence, given a sequence $A_n \in \mathcal A_{<\alpha}$ for each $n \in \mathbb N,$ we can express its union as a monotone one:
$$\bigcup_n A_n = \bigcup_n (A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_n),$$
and so $\mathcal A_\alpha \subseteq \mathcal L.$ It is also clear that $\mathcal A_\alpha$ is still a $\pi$-system, and also closed under finite unions.
Let $A,B,C,D \in \mathcal A_\alpha.$ Because $A \setminus B = A \setminus (A \cap B),$
it is immediate that $\mathcal B_\alpha \subseteq \mathcal L.$ Also, $(A \setminus B) \cap (C \setminus D) = (A \cap C) \setminus (B \cup D),$ and so $\mathcal B_{\alpha}$ is a $\pi$-system.
To finish, notice that $\mathcal A_{<\omega_1}$ is closed under complements ($A \in \mathcal B_{\alpha} \subseteq \mathcal A_{\alpha+1} \implies X \setminus A \in \mathcal B_{\alpha+1}$) and under countable unions (if $A_n \in \mathcal B_{\alpha_n}$ for each $n \in \mathbb N$ and $\alpha_n < \omega_1$ then for $\alpha = \sup_n \alpha_n < \omega_1$ we have $\bigcup_n A_n \in \mathcal B_{\alpha+1}$). So $\mathcal A_{< \omega_1}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and by induction it is contained in $\mathcal L.$
$\square$

Let's me sketch a simpler proof

Note that if a $\lambda$-system is closed under finite intersection, then it's a $\sigma$-algebra.

So, it suffices to prove the generated lambda system $L = \lambda(\mathcal{P})$ is closed under bi-intersection.

Build the lambda system $L$ bottom-up in the following way. Define a double-indexed collections: $P_{\alpha, \beta}$ such that:
$$
P_{\alpha, \beta + 1} = \{U \setminus V | U, V \in P_{\alpha, \beta} \} \\
P_{\alpha^{'} , \beta} = \operatorname{CountableDisjointUnion}({\bigcup_{\alpha < \alpha^{'}} P_{\alpha, \beta}}) \\
L = P_{\omega_1 , \omega}
$$

Now it suffice to prove
$$\forall \alpha \beta \gamma \theta \forall (A, B) \in P_{\alpha, \beta} \times P_{\gamma, \theta} \exists (\eta, \mu, C \in P_{\eta, \mu}) \therefore C = A \cap B $$

Denote this proposition $Q(\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \theta)$, apply induction, we need to prove:
$$
\forall \gamma \theta \therefore Q(0, 0, \gamma, \theta) \\
\forall \gamma \theta \therefore \forall \beta \therefore ( \forall \alpha < \alpha' \therefore Q(\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \theta) ) → Q(\alpha', \beta, \gamma, \theta) \\
\forall \gamma \theta \therefore \forall \alpha, \beta \therefore Q(\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \theta)  → Q(\alpha , \beta + 1, \gamma, \theta) \\
$$
The second and third statement is obvious to prove, apply induction to the first statement again, now it suffices to prove:
$$
Q(0,0,0,0) \\ 
\forall \beta \therefore ( \forall \alpha < \alpha' \therefore Q(0, 0, \alpha, \beta) ) → Q(0, 0, \alpha', \beta) \\
\forall \alpha, \beta \therefore Q(0, 0, \alpha, \beta)  → Q(0, 0, \alpha , \beta + 1) \\
$$
All of which is obvious.
This is actually the approach many textbooks use in a disguised way.



Thanks. Can the $P_\alpha$ be defined in the same way as $\mathcal B_\alpha$ in my question, or is there a simpler way? (I am not aware of the "canonical way").

@Keplerto Yes, it can be defined by similar definition except by using the operation of a $\lambda$-System

I think I understand. If I take $P_0 = \mathcal P,$ and $P_\alpha$ is obtained by taking countable disjoint unions when $\alpha$ is odd, or by taking proper differences when $\alpha$ is even, then the proof is basically the standard one. This method is different than mine in that the intermediate steps are not shown to be $\pi$-systems. However I think that, with some work, one can take $\gamma = \max{\alpha, \beta},$ so this would link both methods.
